# EXCEL vba subroutine pass letter for range update

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

i want to shorten this code and i know it's possible i just dont know the proper syntax

i want to create a subroutine to update the font colors and just call it from the if statements by changing just the first cell letter

would someone mind helping so i can keep this in mind for future reference

thanks in advance,

EDIT: just to clarify, i want to do something like this

```
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C3")) Is Nothing Then 'do the following if e3 is updated

'reset all font colors to black
Range("C8:K9,C14:K14,C37:K37").Font.ColorIndex = 1
Range("C7:K7,C11:K11,C13:K13,C23:K23,C28:K28").Font.ColorIndex = 1
Range("C10:K10,C15:K16").Font.ColorIndex = 1
Range("C17:K17").Font.ColorIndex = 1
Range("C18:K18,C33:K33").Font.ColorIndex = 1
Range("C24:K26,C29:K31").Font.ColorIndex = 1
Range("C32:K32").Font.ColorIndex = 1
Range("C36:K36,C38:K38").Font.ColorIndex = 1

    If Range("C3") = "1" Then ' do the following if C3 is 1
         updateFontColor c
    ElseIf Range("C3") = "2" Then ' do the following if C3 is 2
        updateFontColor d
    ElseIf Range("C3") = "3" Then ' do the following if C3 is 3
          updateFontColor e 
    ElseIf Range("C3") = "4" Then ' do the following if C3 is 4
        updateFontColor f

    ElseIf Range("C3") = "5" Then ' do the following if C3 is 5
        updateFontColor g

    ElseIf Range("C3") = "6" Then ' do the following if C3 is 6
              updateFontColor h     
    ElseIf Range("C3") = "7" Then ' do the following if C3 is 7
            updateFontColor i       
    ElseIf Range("C3") = "8" Then ' do the following if C3 is 8
            updateFontColor j       
    ElseIf Range("C3") = "9" Then ' do the following if C3 is 9
           updateFontColor k
               End If
End If

Sub updateFontColor(x As Range)
        Range("x8:K9,x14:x14,x37:K37").Font.ColorIndex = 2
        Range("x7:K7,x11:K11,x13:K13,x23:K23,x28:K28").Font.ColorIndex = 39
        Range("x10:K10,x15:K16").Font.ColorIndex = 35
        Range("x17:K17").Font.ColorIndex = 28
        Range("x18:K18,x33:K33").Font.ColorIndex = 38
        Range("x24:K26,x29:K31").Font.ColorIndex = 36
        Range("x32:K32").Font.ColorIndex = 44
        Range("x36:K36,x38:K38").Font.ColorIndex = 15
End Sub
```

Comment: chr(65) is "A", so `chr(64+yourcellvalue+2)` will give you the column letter you need.

Comment: sorry, i dont know how that helps, maybe i'm just not getting it, i edited my post to clarify what i want to do....

Comment: If you calculate the column letter from the cell value (and pass to the sub as Jacob showed) then you don't need all those `if... elseif...` statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String concatenation operator: &

Pass the variable `x` as string:

Call your sub by passing a string:

```
updateFontColor("K")
```

The sub:

```
Sub updateFontColor(x As String) 'pass x as string, not range
    Range(x & "8:K9," & x & "14:K14," & x & "37:K37").Font.ColorIndex = 2
    .
    .
    .
End Sub
```